# Curl with XDebug on NetBeans

Tags: php, curl, netbeans, xdebug

I have a strange problem when trying to debug with Xdebug on Netbeans ( on Windows 8 ) a curl request.
Here is my code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
        $result = 'ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
        echo $result;
    }

    print "\n response = \n";
    var_dump($response);

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    die;
```

When I debug with Netbeans I get:

```
ERROR -> 28: Operation timed out after 10015 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes  receivedresponse = bool(false)
```

When I just run without debug I get no error and a response of a xampp page.

In php.ini I have:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = "9000"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that when you set `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`, Xdebug will always attempt to start a remote debugging session and try to connect to a client (even if the GET/POST/COOKIE variable was not present).

May be, in your case, Xdebug try to connect Netbeans but is unable to complete the operation, which this lead Xdebug to `Operation timeout` error.

Comment: I think you have a point. I modified the php.ini to this and it seems to work [XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.4-vc9.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = "9000"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"

Comment: @danpop as far as I see in your comment `xdebug.remote_autostart` still is set to `1`. May be a typo?

Comment: It has a semicolon in front of it, so it's commented out. The clean configuration is this: zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = "9000"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"

Comment: this work thanks a lot. the break point doesn't stop at the curl request but if there is breakpoint in the file the curl is hitting it doesn't go there.

Comment: @NaseeruddinVN, xdebug would not know how to follow a curl request. What if your curl is hitting an external API? how would xdebug obtain source let alone break somewhere along it? Consider curl a point of departure for debugging.